# Drupal 7 Comment Not Posting

Tags: drupal, drupal-comments

I'm having a heck of time trying to get comments to post to my nodes. I've done all the obvious:

Enable comment module,
set appropriate permissions,
etc.

But every time I try to enter a comment it simply redirects to a "Add new comment" page and nothing gets posted. There is no comment in the Content -> Comments section and my database comment table is empty.

The only thing I can find relating to the issue is an error report in my log messages which displays a warning "page not found." I'm using the Drupal Busy theme.

- Type: Page not found
- Location: http://mysite/public://color/busy-0970ccd8/style.css?m
- Message: public://color/busy-0970ccd8/style.css
- Severity: Warning

I've ran the schema module and nothing is funky in with my database. Any thoughts on this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this should be in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll post it there as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a stylesheet from the Color module.  It would normally be at sites/default/files/color/busy-0970ccd8/style.css

Do you have a sites/default/files directory?  Check that you have one at that the directory is writable.  Also check to be sure that the color module is enabled.  Save your theme settings and clear your cache in configuration -- performance.

I'm not sure if a problem retrieving a style sheet from the color module could be causing this.  Seems very unlikely.

You might consider not using the busy theme.  It's current status is "minimally maintained" and the theme authors have [left a note on the project page](http://drupal.org/project/busy) that there will be no further development at this time.

I recommend looking for a theme that is actively maintained and has good support.  It looks like Busy is a pretty standard 960 grid, you might like [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega).

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick. I do have the sites/default/file directory, which contains the style.css file I use to change the styling on my site. The directory is writable. My color module is enabled. Theme settings are saved. Cache has been cleared. Still get redirected to the "Add new comment" page and nothing is written or found in the contents -> comments or the database.